# How to limit length of phone number in xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to return phone number, but only if it is 10 digits.  How do I modify the below to say 'only return the number if its truly 10 digits', otherwise return nothing?

```
<HomePhoneNumber>
   <xsl:value-of select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:Home_Phone"/>
</HomePhoneNumber>
```

Thanks so much!
Jenn

Comment: I should add, the phone number will be already be formatted like this: 1234567890   So I just want to exclude anything that would not have the exact number of 10 digits length.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

```
<xsl:value-of select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:Home_Phone[string-length(.) = 10]"/>
```